# Select specific Calendar when using Java API to create calendar entry

Tags: java, google-api

I have successfully created calendar entries using the Java .jar files for Google Calendar API.  They always go into the "Rifle" calendar even though I have the calendars shown below.  I need to know how to specify the calendar that entry falls under.  For example, where would I specify "Meetings" or "Shotgun"

I'm not seeing anything or any examples of how to specify a particular calendar.

[image: Google Calendar possibilities]

```
    public void create() {
        try {
            CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("My Service");
            myService.setUserCredentials("mycalendar", "mypassword");

            URL postUrl = new URL("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/myurl@junk.com/private/full");

            CalendarEventEntry myEntry = new CalendarEventEntry();
        //myEntry.setIcalUID("Rec Fire");

            DateTime startTime = DateTime.parseDateTime("2014-06-22T09:00:00");
            DateTime endTime = DateTime.parseDateTime("2014-06-22T13:00:00");

                When eventTimes = new When();
            eventTimes.setStartTime(startTime);
            eventTimes.setEndTime(endTime);
            myEntry.addTime(eventTimes);
            Where eventLocation = new Where();
            eventLocation.setLabel("R-4");
            eventLocation.setValueString("value string");
            eventLocation.setRel("REL");
            myEntry.addLocation(eventLocation);
            EventWho eventWho = new EventWho();
        eventWho.setAttendeeStatus("attendee status");
            eventWho.setAttendeeType("Meetings");
            eventWho.setValueString("who value string");
            eventWho.setEmail("myemailt@email.com");
            eventWho.setRel("who rel");
        myEntry.addParticipant(eventWho);
            myEntry.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("R-4 Rifles Only"));
            myEntry.setContent(new PlainTextConstruct("Paragraph HURST MULLINS"));


            CalendarEventEntry insertedEntry = myService.insert(postUrl,  myEntry);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: It helps if you post the code that you are using to create the calendar entry, so we can figure out what to change in it. For a general example you'll need to go to the [Google documentation (linked)](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_java#CreatingEvents)

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  First you have to get the IDs of your secondary calendars

```
    public void retrieve() {
        try {
            CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("QuanticoShootingclub");
            myService.setUserCredentials("calendar@quanticoshootingclub.com", "washington13");

            URL feedUrl = new URL("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/owncalendars/full");
            CalendarFeed resultFeed = myService.getFeed(feedUrl, CalendarFeed.class);

            System.out.println("Your calendars:");
            System.out.println();

            for (int i = 0; i < resultFeed.getEntries().size(); i++) {
                CalendarEntry entry = resultFeed.getEntries().get(i);
                System.out.println("\t" + entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
                System.out.println("\t\t" + entry.getId());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

You can also do this by goign to your Google Calendar on the web.  Click the drop-down and then Calendar Settings > Calendar Address: (Calendar ID: @group.calendar.google.com)

Then, when you're creating the new calendar entry, you substitute this ID for the primary ID.

NOTE:  From the original code

```
           URL postUrl = new URL("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/***<secondary calendar ID>***/private/full");
```